# Xamarin Android How to declare Intent Filter correctly to match custom file types?

Tags: android, xamarin, intentfilter

I am currently working on an app which features should include a custom file extension to which my app is connected. What I basically want is that when I click the custom file in the Android file system my app starts automatically and reads the file contents. To achieve this I tried to implement an Intent Filter, but I just can't get it to work.

How my IntentFilter looks:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataMimeType ="*/*" ,DataSchemes = new[] { "file","content" }, DataPathPattern = ".*\\.cm")]
```

My problem is that this filter does recognize `.cm` files but also every other file which is not what I want. I tried many different solutions which didn't match every file type but also not files of type `.cm`. Also I read that `DataHost` has to be specified or otherwise `DataPathPattern` will be ignored, but when I also include `DataHost` in the declaration, nothing works anymore.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use `StartActivityForResult(intent, PICK_DIR_REQUEST_CODE);` to start the intent, then judge if the intent filter  will match custom files in the `OnActivityResult`, use `if (requestCode == PICK_DIR_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Result.Ok)`

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks for your answer. As I am very new to Xamarin and Android I read a bit about `StartActivityForResult` but I don't see how it'd help me in this case. I edited my question as it probably wasn't clear enough on what I want to achieve but basically I want my App to handle the filetype if the user interacts with e.g. in the file browser.

Comment: I post an answer, please see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following result?
[image]

If so, please change your `IntentFilter` like following format.

```
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView, Android.Content.Intent.ActionEdit }, Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "application/octet-stream", DataHost = "*", DataPathPattern = ".*\\.cm")]
```

You can google:Registering Your Android App for File Types and Email Attachments, It is an helpful article about it

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Okay, I see that the filter works on your emulator but when I try it on my physical testing device (Samsung SM-J500FN on Android 6.0) I still get the "No application" message. The ```.cm``` files are opened in the native file browser by the way.

Comment: Could you try it with other device or emulator, do not use samsung device to make a test.

Comment: I tried an emulator and also another physical device which runs Android 5.1 and both accept your declaration of the filter interestingly enough. The only problem is that my method of getting the file contents through ```GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream) as Android.Net.Uri``` does not work anymore on those devices but I guess that is another topic in itself. I do wonder though if it is a Samsung or an Android 6.0 thing that a perfectly matching IntentFilter does not seem possible. Anyways you pointed me in the right direction and provided a working filter. I really thank you for that!